# How to count near circular objects in image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, geometry, object-recognition

I have a image similar to below. In that I need to find all red circles and count them. So, I am thinking to use MATLAB R2011a with Image Processing Toolkit for it. How could I possibly extract them?

[image]

Comment: You need to be way more specific for us to help you. What have you tried? What are your requirements?

Comment: Perhaps first filter all pixels that are red enough, and then blur that a bit?

Comment: do you want to draw all the circles/partial circles, or just count how many red fruits there?

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a starting point:

```
v=double(img)/255;
mask = v(:,:,3)+v(:,:,2)-v(:,:,1)<0;
mask = imopen(mask,strel('square',3));
imagesc(min(1,v+cat(3,mask*0,mask*1,mask*0)));axis image
```

The overlay image looks like:[image]

use RANSAC (as suggested by AdrienNK) on the mask and you'll get the location (and count) of your tomatoes ;-)

-O-

Comment: for instance, if the tomatoes are of green color > "n". Does the mask `v(:,:,3) + v(:,:,1) + v(:,:,2) > n` will do the job? I just tried on an image but its not working

Comment: can you actually explain the second statement you have written clearly.. I think the mask should be something like `v(:,:,1) < 0`

Comment: having red color(1st channel) means high red and almost no green and blue. In other words that the red value is greater than the green and blue colors combined

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use some filter the points on this picture (as Dennis suggested, filter the ones that aren't red enough). Then you could implement a (Disk) RANSAC (RANdom SAmple Consensus) to find disks within this filtered picture.

RANSAC will use a bit of tuning but then will be able to count quite properly the different objects you are trying to find.

There are a lot of good implementations of RANSAC already done in matlab.